# Modify repeated values in javaScript

Tags: javascript

There is an array of JavaScript:

```
let arr=[
[220,A,12],
[560,B,5],
[300,A,0],
[300,H,3], 
[300,K,T],
[450,P,9],
[500,E,6],
[500,M,8]
];
```

The first element of sub-arrays have some repeated values,
I want to find them and modify the repeated values, as follow:

```
[300,A,0],  ===>  remain unchanged
[300,H,3],  ===>  [320,H,3],  //First element add 20
[300,K,T],  ===>  [340,K,T],  //First element add 20 again

[500,E,6],  ===>  remain unchanged
[500,M,8]   ===>  [520,M,8] //First element add 20
```

That is, the first element adds 20 in proper order if repeated.
Other elements don't need to be considered.
How to do it in javaScript?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck? Please show us your own attempts.

Comment: Please may you read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `reduce`. I pass an object as the initial value to `reduce`:

```
{
    last: null,  // The previous number encountered
    offset: 20,  // The amount to add on repeat
    data: []     // The new array
}
```

Then, use this to build the new array:

```js
let arr=[
[220,'A',12],
[560,'B',5],
[300,'A',0],
[300,'H',3], 
[300,'K','T'],
[450,'P',9],
[500,'E',6],
[500,'M',8]
];

arr = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    // Is this a repeat?
    if (prev.last == cur[0]) {
        cur[0] += prev.offset;
        prev.offset += 20;
    }
    // Not a repeat. Reset.
    else {
        prev.last = cur[0];
        prev.offset = 20;
    }
    prev.data.push(cur);
    return prev;
}, {last: null, offset: 20, data: []}).data;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

using map key:value, where key is number and value is its occurrence so far

```js
let arr = [
  [220, 12],
  [560, 5],
  [300, 0],
  [300, 3],
  [300, 0],
  [450, 9],
  [500, 6],
  [500, 8]
];

m = {}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   const x = arr[i][0]
    if (m[x] > 0){
      arr[i][0] += (m[x]) *20
      m[x]++
   } else m[x] = 1
}

console.log(arr)
```